# Work With the Data Recently Injected on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm injecting on my html page a html table from an external source and then running a function with the table data. The table is below:

```
<table id="yy">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Values</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>John</th>
            <td>42</td>
            <td data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66 "/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Gus</th>
            <td>36</td>
            <td data-sparkline="87, 44, 74, 41 "/>
        </tr>
</table>
```

and I use the following piece of code to get that table from the external source and inject it on my page (where "myid" is the id of the element which is the parent of the table):

```
$.get( "example/filename.txt" )
    .done(function( data ) {
        $( "#myid" ).html( data );
    });
```

So far it works fine but I have trouble after that because I have a second function that uses the data of that table. But the way it works is executing the following piece of code:

```
$tds = $('td[data-sparkline]')
```

But it doesn't find any values in `$('td[data-sparkline]')` - the data is there when I look the source code, but the script don't find it - I suppose because I have just injected it on the page. What should I do to be able to find the values? I know we can use jquery with the "on" event in some cases but it doesn't seem to fit in this example.

Comment: You have to call second function from ajax callback, because ajax is async. Your code could be: `$( "#myid" ).load('example/filename.txt', secondFunctionRef)`

Comment: Awesome! That works, thanks a ton :)